# I accidentally deleted protected google chrome app. Now it is nowhere in phone. Please help me to get it back

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I have a protected folder in my Lenovo zuk z1 phone, where Google chrome browser was there. I pressed the cross button beside it accidentally. Now I could not find it anywhere to replace it back. My phone doesn't have app drawer facility. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need to replace the file or folder back?

Download [Chrome from Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome)